# SQL get AVG from COL1, Where COL2 = 0

Tags: mysql, sql, average

I've searched for answers and tried for the last 5 hours, but can't figure it out. So I ask your help.

I have two columns COL 1 (size) and COL2 (material). Bot have numeric values.

So I need to get Average for SIZE, but sort by MATERIALS that have a value of ZERO ( = 0 )

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT material, AVG( size ) 
FROM results
WHERE material =0
```

This gives me incorrect number.

**Also**

How do is sort out SIZE if it is > 1000 (preferably all at once).

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the average where materials are not 0, then use the right condition in the `where`:

```
SELECT AVG( size ) 
FROM results
WHERE material <> 0;
```

You can also filter out sizes that are too big:

```
SELECT AVG( size ) 
FROM results
WHERE material <> 0 AND size <= 1000;
```

Comment: Linoff, i need AVG where material IS = 0 (or any number) ... I want to sort by material ID. Thanks

Comment: @RoofingCalculator . . . Perhaps you should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.